# How can I convert values in sql query output from 1 to yes

Tags: sql

If i run:
'select PolicyName, Enabled from PolicyTable'

The output will show Enabled as a "0" or a "1".  Can I convert the output to show it as a "Yes" or "No"  (1 = Yes; 0 = No)

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which SQL server are you using (that might make a difference in the syntax to be used)

Comment: thank you. I tried googling suggestions, which lead me to the output clause.  It seemed rather complicated for what I wanted to do.   In the real example I had to find the data and then join it across 3 tables.  I was kind of fried when I got to this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression.

```
Select case when Enabled=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columns
 ,CASE
    WHEN ENABLED = 1 THEN 'yes'
    WHEN ENABLED = 0 THEN 'no'
END as Result
FROM t
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, of course you're right. My mistake .... different programming languages.